# How to prevent Sql Injection in stored queries designed for later use? Automation Systems

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am working with a .net webtool and our clients require some extremely large queries that are just plain not viable for our web servers use. Our solution was to kick the query back to our automation system and feed the data back to the user when its finished. The problem is, passing the query from the webtool to automation requires we store the query as a string for later use. This does not allow us to use parameterized inputs.

What is best practice here? How can we scrub this data before running it? Obviously, the inputs should be validated initially but I am looking for a more, catchall solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the threat model here?

Comment: Where are you storing the query?  It sounds like you're storing the query in your database, and executing it again at a later date.  Are you worried about someone modifying the stored query?  If that's what you're worried about, at that point your database would have already been compromised, and SQL injection is a rather moot point...

Comment: Hey stuartd, thank you. I am not familiar with completing a threat model but I can say our data is very sensitive and our application is private and strongly secured.

Comment: @siyual, the query is generated at the webtool and stored in a table designed to hold them for later use. Any queries we run directly from the webtool utilize paramterized variables, but this is unique because the SQL is stored as a complete string

Comment: Serialization? I'm assuming SqlDataAdapter objects are involved here. I'm not certain these can be serialized "out of the box."

Comment: if possible, a simple solution could be to create a user with read only permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a some assumptions made in the question that need to be validated, such as the statement "we store the query as a string for later use. This does not allow us to use parameterized inputs."  It is possible to use parameterized queries, and storing the complete SQL content as a string. Below is an example of a parameterized query:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @monthNo int = 2
declare @minAmount decimal = 100

set @sql = N'select column1, column2 from dbo.Mytable where mon = @MonthNo and amount > @minAmount'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@monthNo int, @minAmount decimal', @monthNo, @minAmount
```

If the above example is not a viable option, here is some syntax to catch injection attempts within a string:

```
-- check for sql injection
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = N'My fancy sql query; truncate table dbo.VeryImportantTable'
IF CHARINDEX(';', ISNULL(@sql,'')) != 0 OR CHARINDEX('--', ISNULL(@sql,'')) != 0
BEGIN
 RAISERROR('Invalid input parameter', 16, 1)
 RETURN -1
END
```

Since there are no examples in the question of code or its implementation, the answer contains some degree of speculation.

Answer (score 0):

**Summing :**

Just to make it clearer for me and give my understanding :

1) You've got users that provide large queries via a webtool.

2) Your webtool give them to an automation system via SQL server.

3) Your automation system with SQL dynamic will query and feed back results to your users.

I assume that you will put 2 single quotes on each single quote at step 2) in order to reduce your query to something "storable".

**Solution :**

I think it will be nearly impossible to protect yourself of your user at this point without changing your architecture. But if you really want to keep it, the simpliest things you can do here is an analytics at step 1) and store your query without any edit at step 2).

**Example :**

I assume that you already had your own set of rules to analyse your query so I will just talk about "storing query".

Two ways to go. One is not using SQL Server to store query like a file (that is the safest solution and probably the worst in term of performance).

The second is to use special replacement of your single quote character and convert back at execution time (it's safe until someone now of your replacent character(s)).

Comment: Well its not storing the query that is unsafe for us. Its the execution. If they input an sql injection in one of our input fields, we still store the string safely, its when we pick it back up from the automation system to execute the it that we are at risk.

Comment: So your problem is only the analysis of your query and should be verified at step 1) without execution of the actual query. You should have some tools on the web that can make it (to forbid create/delete/truncate/select on system tables/ etc). But you will never be able to totally protect yourself (except if you forbid all but select).

Checking your query at step 3) is also possible but someone should be able to break your "safe storing" (using escaping character for example).